# The type java.awt.geom.AffineTransform cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: java, android, pdf-generation, itext

I am generating PDF file using ItextPdf but I am getting an exception on this line  `canvas.addImage(background, width, 0,0, height, 20, 430);` i.e. The type `java.awt.geom.AffineTransform` cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required `.class` files . On this line I am trying to set background image. Please help me out from this exception.

```
public void createPDF() throws NumberFormatException, ParseException
{
    list1.add("I-Tax Number : ");
   list1.add("Category : ");
     list1.add("Service : ");
     list1.add("Number : ");
     list1.add("Amount : ");
     list1.add("Status : ");

     list2.add(iTaxNumber);
     list2.add("Bill Payment");
     list2.add("Idea Postapid");
     list2.add("9644212111");
     list2.add("100");

     list2.add("SUCCESS");

    Font trfont = new Font(FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 12, Font.BOLDITALIC,
            new BaseColor(130, 130, 140));

    Font otherfont  = new Font(FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 12, Font.NORMAL,
            new BaseColor(160, 160, 160));

    Font datefont  = new Font(FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 12, Font.BOLD,
            new BaseColor(130, 130, 140));

    Font thanksFont = new Font(FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 14, Font.BOLDITALIC,
            new BaseColor(130, 130, 140));

    Document doc = new Document(new Rectangle(792, 612));

    try {
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/PDF";

        File dir = new File(path);
        if(!dir.exists())
            dir.mkdirs();

        Log.d("PDFCreator", "PDF Path: " + path);

        File file = new File(dir, "demo98989.pdf");
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

        PdfWriter  docPdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, fOut);

        Paragraph fromTotoDate = new Paragraph("Date : 25-oct-2015", datefont);
        fromTotoDate.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
        fromTotoDate.setIndentationRight(5);

        doc.addAuthor("betterThanZero");
        doc.addCreationDate();
        doc.addProducer();
        doc.addCreator("www.xyz.com");
        doc.setPageSize(PageSize.A4);
        doc.open();

        PdfPTable table = setTable(list1, list2);
        Paragraph trId = new Paragraph("Transaction Id : 889879899", trfont);
        trId.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
        trId.setIndentationRight(65);
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph("\n\n\n\n");
        Paragraph nextline = new Paragraph("\n");// for blank line
        doc.add(fromTotoDate);
        doc.add(p);
        doc.add(trId);


        int list1size =  list1.size();
        String size = String.valueOf(list1size);
        Image trDetails_Icon;


        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getBaseContext().getResources(),R.drawable.trreceipt);
           ByteArrayOutputStream streamTrReceipt = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
           bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, streamTrReceipt);

           trDetails_Icon = Image.getInstance(streamTrReceipt.toByteArray());
           trDetails_Icon.scaleAbsolute(445f, 238f);
           trDetails_Icon.setAbsolutePosition(76, 516);
           doc.add(trDetails_Icon);



           doc.add(nextline);
            doc.add(table);



                Paragraph thanktouMessage = new Paragraph("Thanks for Being with Us ! ", thanksFont);
                thanktouMessage.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                doc.add(nextline);
                doc.add(thanktouMessage);
                Font contFont = new Font(FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 10, Font.NORMAL,
                        new BaseColor(130, 130, 140));
                doc.add(nextline);
                Paragraph cont = new Paragraph("For more info contact us", contFont);

                cont.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
                cont.setIndentationRight(20);
                doc.add(cont);

                System.out.println("list2.get(1) = "+list2.get(1));


                float width;
                float height;
                Image background;

               Bitmap bmp1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getBaseContext().getResources(),R.drawable.trans);
               ByteArrayOutputStream streamTrReceipt1 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
               bmp1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, streamTrReceipt1);

               System.out.println("list2.get(1) = "+list2.get(1)+"ELSE");
               width = PageSize.A4.getWidth()-40;
                     height = (PageSize.A4.getHeight()/2)-25;
                      background = Image.getInstance(streamTrReceipt1.toByteArray());


                     PdfContentByte canvas =  docPdfWriter.getDirectContentUnder();

                    canvas.addImage(background, width, 0,0, height, 20, 430);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Created...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } catch (DocumentException de) {
        Log.e("PDFCreator", "DocumentException:" + de);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("PDFCreator", "ioException:" + e);
    } 
    finally
    {
        doc.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong iText version. You should use [iTextG](http://itextpdf.com/product/itextg) instead of the "plain Java" iText version. As an Android developer, you know that it's forbidden to use `java.awt` (and `javax.nio`,...) classes on Android.

The "plain Java" iText uses classes that aren't whitelisted on Android (e.g. in the `PdfGraphics2D` class). That's why we've created iTextG. iTextG is essentially identical to iText, except that we've removed all dependencies on the "forbidden classes" (and `java.awt.geom.AffineTransform` is one of those classes).

There is slightly less functionality in iTextG (we had to drop `PdfGraphics2D`), but at first sight, I don't see anything that isn't supported in iTextG in your code.

Long story short: replace iText with its Android port iTextG and your problem will be solved.

Comment: I'm curious, are those classes "forbidden" or just not present in the Java API subset that Google chose to use in Android?  I thought it was the latter but I could be wrong.

Comment: Not present in the Java API subset that Google chose to use in Android. The Dalvik VM doesn't know about them. The reasons: a different imaging model and different treatment of files, especially in the context of Google App Engine (a *file system* in the cloud is different than a file system on disk).